Given $f_n\to g$ uniformly on $A$, $g$ is bounded, and $h$ is continuous, prove that $h(f_n)\to h(g)$ uniformly on $A$.
This is an exercise from my Intro to Real Analysis class. I wrote the following proof:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary.
Since $h$ is continuous, we can select $\delta_k>0$ such that, for all $x\in A$,
$$|f_k(x)-g(x)|<\delta_k\implies |h(f_k(x))-h(g(x))|<\varepsilon$$
Let $\delta=\inf\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\ldots\}$. Since $f_n(x)\to g$ uniformly, we can select $m\geq1$ such that, for all $x\in A$,
$$\ell\geq m\implies |f_\ell(x)-g(x)|<\delta$$
Then,
$$\ell\geq m\implies |f_\ell(x)-g(x)|<\delta\leq\delta_\ell\implies |h(f_\ell)-h(g)|<\varepsilon$$
Therefore, $h\circ f_n\to h\circ g$ uniformly. $\square$

Now, I'm 99% sure this proof is incorrect because:

How can I be sure $\delta=\inf\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\ldots\}$ exists?
I didn't use the fact that $g$ is bounded anywhere in this proof.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It exists (the inf) because $\eta_k >0$ so it is minored by $0$. And ${ \delta_k , k \in \mathbb{N} }$ isn't empty. So the $inf$ exists.
But you should take here the $\sup$ and it isn't clear to use it.
Rather use every point, was is $k$ ? It is rather $\delta_\epsilon$
And your $\delta_l$, how do you compare to $\delta$ ? And as said below it is false.

Hint: The claim is false.

How is the claim false? I'm even more confused now...

Take $A=\mathbb R$ (even imposing that $A$ be compact will not solve the issue). Set $g(x)=(1+e^x)^{-1}$ and $f_n = g+1/n$. Take $h=1/x$. (Note $h$ is continuous on $g(A)$ and $f_n(A)$.) Then $h\circ g$ is unbounded whereas $h\circ f_n$ is bounded for every $n$. In particular, the convergence is not uniform.
You may be able to obtain a true statement if you impose further restrictions. Some natural candidates are insisting $h$ be continuous on the entire real line, or $A$ be compact and $g$ continuous (I do not guarantee that these will work).

I believe the question meant "$h$ is continuous (everywhere)" — that's my bad, I should've been more specific.
